# How to change display brightness in Dota 2: Reborn?

Tags: technical-issues, dota-2

So Dota 2: Reborn was rolled out just now.

But I don't seem to find a brightness slider. It's very dark, especially on an IPS panel. Very hard to play.

Is there a console command which can change brightness/gamma, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, turns out you can change brightness, in order to do that:

1. Go to `Options > Video`
2. Select `Use advanced settings`
3. Change `Display Mode` (from `Borderless Window`) to `Exclusive Fullscreen`.
4. Press `Apply`.

**Brightness control appears only in Fullscreen mode.**

Comment: Well, it was normal question...i don't think this should be on SO. and you asked for console command in question and then giving answer which is findable in just 3 sec or google's first page..

Comment: I asked for a console command, because it seemed like there is no brightness slider in the game. Turns out there is, but it's *hidden*. I did a google search before posting the question, and it turned up a bunch of people asking the same thing, but not receiving an clear cut answer.

Comment: yes that's what my point that you asked for console command but you did not provide console command and in reborn, and in every game, for display setting you have to go in video so what's new in your answer? its normal, and won't help others..please don't take me in wrong way but hope you will get my points..thanx and sorry.